# Have jest ignore babel config

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs

I am getting this error:

> Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory

I have `jest` in a package with `babel`, the babel dependencies are not installed, which is why I am getting this error, but the file I am testing is the source, and with the version of node that I'm running I don't need to compile, I only have babel in the project to ship the code I'm building as a `postinstall` script on lesser-versions of node then authored.

How can I shut off `jest` from forcing `babel` dependencies from being installed?